# it doesnt throw error when it fails. I'm running it in SQL agent job

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssis, sql-agent-job, dtexec

```
dtexec /SQL "\Export table" /SERVER svr1 /USER User1 /PASSWORD "*******" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E
```

I also added this part

```
"/Par "$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)";True"
```

but it throws an error:

> Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'The term 'True' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax provided is incorrect since there are some additional quotations. Try the following syntax:

```
 /Par "$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)";True
```

**Reference**

- [Integration Services Server and Project File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-2017#server)